# jQuery change dropdown list selected boolean value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a `WebGrid` with one of the columns is a series of Select button.

```
grid.Column("Update", format:@<text>          
    <button class="editBtn display-mode">Edit</button>
        <button class="cancelBtn edit-mode">Cancel</button>
        </text>, style: "col3Width", canSort: false)
```

After clicking it, a form is supposed to be populated with the data in that row.

```
$(document).ready(
        function () {
        $('.editBtn').on('click', function () {
            var selectedRowData = $(this).closest('tr').find('span');
            $('#IS_MALE').val(selectedRowData.eq(7).val());
         })});
```

As you can see `IS_MALE` is the <s>7th</s> 8th column on the row.

```
grid.Column("isMale","Gender is Male?",format:@<text> <span class="display-mode">@item.IS_MALE  </span>
```

In the model:

```
public Nullable<bool> {get; set;}
```

All other fields (which are textboxes) in the form are populated, except for this one, which contains boolean values of `true` and `false`. What should I do?

Comment: So there's at least eight spans in the row, as you're getting all the spans, and then the eight as `eq` is zero-based. You're not getting the seventh column here ?

Comment: You need to show the actual html which your generating for a typical row. `selectedRowData` is returning a collection of `<span>` elements. Then `selectedRowData.eq(7)` gets the 8th `<span>` in that collection. But then `selectedRowData.eq(7).val()` returns undefined because a `<span>` does not have a `.val()` property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want to select a dropdown list option that matches whatever inside the <span> tags.

Comment: Yes I know. But we cant show you the correct code to do that unless you include the html for a typical row in your table (in particular the 8th `<td>` element).

Comment: @StephenMuecke `<td class="col1Width"><span class="display-mode">True</span></td>`

Comment: `selectedRowData.eq(7).text()` will return `'True'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the value of a span.  Change that to .text()

So

```
.selectedRowData.eq(7).val();
```

should be changed to

```
.selectedRowData.eq(7).text();
```

I believe this should fix your issues unless you have something else wrong with your code.